# Reading & Writing to the same file from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

Given a file `foo`

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Can someone help me understand why the following results in an empty file?

```
cat foo | grep 1 > foo
wc foo
0       0       0 foo
```

whereas the following appends fine

```
cat foo | grep 1 >> foo
cat foo
1
2
3
4
5
1
```

I'm not surprised with the functioning of `>>`, but with `>` my expectation was that the file will contain just the output of `cat foo | grep 1`. What's the underlying implementation detail that results in this behaviour?

```
cat foo | tee foo
```

on the other hand does not empty the file.

Comment: All parts of a pipeline run in parallel. This means `>foo` empties the file _while the pipeline is being set up_. None of this is in any way terminal-specific -- a shell not connected to a terminal behaves the same way.

Comment: In `cat foo | tee foo`, `tee` _may_ open the file with the `O_TRUNC`  and thus empty its contents before `cat` finishes reading from it -- it's a race condition. There's no guarantee that it will or won't, so any code that assumes either way is inherently buggy. If you're reliably getting results that mean that `cat` wins the race, then you're obviously testing with (relatively) small files, and on systems with predictable timing characteristics. :)

Comment: you are right about tee. in some occurrences the file was empty indeed

Comment: BTW, general note, prefer `<foo` to `cat foo |`. It doesn't make a huge difference for `grep`, but a lot of standard UNIX tools can optimize their performance when given a seekable file descriptor -- `sort` can have different threads sort different subsets of the file in parallel and merge the results; `tail` and `tac` can jump direct to the end without reading intervening content (and `tac` can move the file pointer backwards towards the front of the file as it goes); `wc -c` can just use `seek()` and `tell()` (or a `stat`-family syscall) to check the file's size in constant time; etc.

Comment: The `>>` approach can also have unintended behaviors if your file is large enough -- if `cat foo | grep 1 >>foo` means that `grep` is appending content to the file as fast as `cat` can read from it (and the file is long enough that `cat` doesn't reach end-of-file in a single read operation) you can end up in an endless loop.

Comment: thanks! i guess `cat foo |` has been in my muscle memory for a while now. I didn't know it could have a stark difference

Comment: you can end up in an endless loop – i was curious about this indeed, but i was experimenting with small files and hence did not observe the case you mentioned